# How to POST with parameters using curl to a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, http, curl

How do I use the command line tool `curl` to post to a WCF service that has more than 1 parameter?

I have a service like the following

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    void PostMethod(string varString, bool varBool);
}
```

And I setup the server like this

```
var service = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService),
    new Uri("http://localhost:3000/MyService");
service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
service.Open();
```

How do I call this method via curl?

```
curl -d varString=foo -d varBool=true http://localhost:3000/MyService/PostMethod
```

Where does the error lie? Is the BodyStyle of the method wrong? Should I wrap the parameters in a [DataContract] class like the following?

```
[DataContract]
public class PostMethodResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string varString { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool varBool { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revised answer:

URI template will not work for using curl to post request to web service. WebInvoke expects the POST body to be either XML or JSON.

WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare does not work because you have 2 parameters so you have to wrap.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string PostMethod(string varString, bool varBool);
```

The post body shape looks like this:

```
 <PostMethod  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><varString>1</varString><varBool>true</varBool> </PostMethod>
```

Using UriTemplate you pass the values via URI so it's a POST but with empty body.

The closest option with curl you could use is JSON

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string PostMethodJson(string varString, bool varBool);
```

It ain't pretty but you can then use this:

```
curl -d"{\"varString\":\"so99\",\"varBool\":\"true\"}"  -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost:3000/MyService/PostMethodJson
```

Comment: This does not respond to `curl -s -d varString=foo -d varBool=true http://localhost:3000/MyService/PostMethod`. Although it does work if I do this instead `curl -s -d doesnot=matter http://localhost:3000/MyService/PostMethod?varString=foo&varBool=true`. It would be nice to not have to supply the data parameter or use it for the data instead of the url.

Comment: Hmm i have tried this and it worked here (i did run curl from powershell). Let me see why there is a difference.

Comment: I'm using .net 4.0 without the default endpoints. Although I don't think that would cause it to work for you and not for me. Did you do something to the content-type?